# How to create custom Android xml ids?

Tags: android, xml

How can I create custom Android xml ids?

In Android we have:

```
@android:id/...
```

Is it possible to create something like:

```
@project_name:id/...
```

I can create ids.xml and define identifiers but I want to have "project_name" prefix.

Comment: Probably it has something to do with the xml namespace (you know that **xmlns:android** that appears in your layouts definitions)

Answer (score 0):

The project name prefix isn't required.  Instead, you would reference your custom id defined in ids.xml as `@id/my_custom_id`.

The `android` namespace just allows you to specify attributes that are part of the framework instead of your project.  There is no need for namespacing of these values inside your own project.

Comment: I know that it's not required but I want to have this prefix for my purposes.